Laravel 10 artisan PHP Startup: Invalid date.timezone value '', using 'UTC' instead
I am using Laravel 10.x and I am running artisan command using Cronjob /opt/alt/php82/usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1 every minute as follows:

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $schedule->command('emails:send-scheduled')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('emails:send-order-reminder')->everyFiveMinutes();
        
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands(): void
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}



And commands are executed just fine. But I warning is logged in error_log file
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid date.timezone value '', using 'UTC' instead in Unknown on line 0

I have configured timezone (Europe/Zagreb) in app settings and correct time is shown across the app. It's just when ever artisan is exexuted it's not picking up timezone and warning is logged.
I am running app on cPanel and I have already tried with setting timezone in htaccess file and as well creating php.ini files to override it.
I have tried adding ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Zagreb');  to artisan and different files to force timezone but no joy.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Is it possible that your config is cached? Try to run php artisan config;cache to see if that helped

I have tried that as well and no joy

The "timezone" value in config/app.php can lead to this warning message. Can you confirm it is in the list of supported timezones at https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php ?

Yes confirming that it's in the list and I have it set as:
'timezone' => 'Europe/Zagreb',
